# How to Check if Document Contains an Element

Tags: javascript, dom, contains

I'm trying to check if the DOM contains an element with ID = "htmlFileLink."

```js
let element = document.createElement('a');
element.id = 'htmlFileLink';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', element );

if( document.body.contains( document.getElementById('htmlFileLink') ) ) {
 alert ('yes');
}
else {
 alert ('no');
}
```

Why is it alerting "no" instead of "yes?"

Comment: Because there's no elements in the body. `insertAdjacentHTML` waits for a HTML string as an argument, not an element. Use `appendChild` to append new elements to existing elements.

Comment: OK, this is the answer I was looking for, appendChild(). Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7):

The [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method adds a node to the end of the list of `children` of a specified `parent` node. If the given `child` is a reference to an existing node in the `document`, `appendChild()` moves it from its current position to the new position.

**DEMO**

```js
let element = document.createElement('a');
element.id = 'htmlFileLink';
element.innerText = 'Test';
document.body.appendChild(element);

if (document.body.contains(document.getElementById('htmlFileLink'))) {
  alert('yes');
} else {
  alert('no');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of **[`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)** must be a HTML.

*Example*

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<a id="htmlFileLink">Ele</a>');

if (document.body.contains(document.getElementById('htmlFileLink'))) {
  console.log('yes');
} else {
  console.log('no');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

> `insertAdjacentHTML()` parses the specified text as HTML or XML and
>   inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position.

That means that the function always expects the second argument to be a valid *string of HTML, not a DOM element*.

Look at the below snippet to make sure:

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<a id="htmlFileLink"></a>');

if (document.body.contains(document.getElementById('htmlFileLink'))) {
  alert ('yes');
} else {
  alert ('no');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating element
try to do below its simple and easy.

`enter code here`

```
<script>

if(document.getElementById('htmlFileLink')) {
    alert ('yes');
}
else {
    alert ('no');
}
</script>
```